# Rails sending AJAX response with a textarea

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the following form:

```
<%= form_for(@document, :remote => true) do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :asset, "Document to Upload" %><br />
        <%= f.file_field :asset, :class => "behaves", "data-behave" => "passValueOnChange", "data-recipient" => "#campaign_document_name" %>

      <%= f.label :name, :class => 'required' %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name, :required => true %>

    <%= f.submit "Upload Document", :class => "button" %>

<% end %>
```

to submit to the following controller:

```
def create
@document = CampaignDocument.new(params[:campaign_document])
@campaign.documents << @document
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

which should return the following `create.js.erb`:

```
 <%= remotipart_response do %>
  <% unless @document.errors.any? %>
    $('.tablewrapper').html( '<%= escape_javascript(render :partial=>'documents_table') %>' );
    alertify.success("File Updloaded");
  <% else %>
    <% @document.errors.each do |attr, msg|%>
    alertify.error("<%= msg %>",10000);
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

but the response is wrapped in a `textare` tag. Which is pretty odd:

```
<textarea data-type="text/javascript" response-code="200">
    $('.tablewrapper').html('{code for HTML ommited for brevity}');
    alertify.success(&quot;File Updloaded&quot;);
</textarea>
```

*Note*
Other, similar styled AJAX functions on the same installation are not behaving this way.

Comment: It seems to be a normal behaviour of remotipart...
http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-ajax-file-uploads-with-remotipart/

Comment: It works here. It says : Secondly, Remotipart provides the remotipart_response block method in our response js.erb views. This method first checks to see if the form was hijacked by Remotipart and was thus submitted in an iFrame, and if so, it returns our generated JS inside a textarea element, so that it automatically gets executed in our parent window. See https://github.com/formasfunction/remotipart/blob/master/lib/remotipart/view_helper.rb#L7

Comment: these two comments could be answer

Answer (score 0):

This error happen beacause of gem "remotipart".
This branch was not merged with jangosteve/remotipart master.
You can fix it by updating in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'remotipart', :git => 'https://github.com/westonganger/remotipart', :branch => 'fix_escape_javascript'
```

You can get reference of this issue here:
https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/473
https://github.com/formasfunction/remotipart/blob/master/lib/remotipart/view_helper.rb#L7